# Running flink job on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying out flink job on  kubernetes with latest version of flink 1.5.

[Flink on Kubernetes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html) document defines how to deploy flink and I used minikube in mac. The flink ui comes up nicely showing the job manager and task manager.

The question I have is how to run a example app on the above flink cluster. [The flink example project](https://github.com/sanderploegsma/flink-k8s) has information how to build a docker image with flink app  and submit that application to flink. I followed the example, just changed version of flink to latest. I find the application (example-app)  is submitted successfully and shows in pod in kubernetes, but the flink UI does not show any running jobs. Can someone please point me to an example of how to submit a flink job to flink cluster running on kubernetes.

Comment: When you run `kubectl get pods --show-all` do you see the job? What's its status?

Comment: Yes it shows up there only the running job is not visible in flink ui.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Minikube's VM that a pod cannot reference a service pointing to itself. Here is the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1568).

You have to log into the Minikube VM to set the proper `ip link`. The following command should do the trick

```
minikube ssh 'sudo ip link set docker0 promisc on'
```

The reason why we need this is because the web submission handler which runs on the cluster entrypoint needs to connect to the cluster entrypoint to submit the job.

Comment: I tried the above and the application seems to be running in the pod but nothing is displayed in the UI. The application logs does not have much information either. `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
default       example-app-s62rb                       1/1       Running   0          9m
default       flink-jobmanager-79c5f48c5b-k75nr       1/1       Running   0          2d
default       flink-taskmanager-7679c9d55d-rfnjj      1/1       Running   0          2d
default       flink-taskmanager-7679c9d55d-vwqnm      1/1       ...` `kubectl logs example-app-s62rb
Starting execution of program`

Comment: Could you share the log files with us?